# How can I change Access hyperlinks with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've done some extensive research and realize this is not an easy task.

I need to change many hyperlinks in different tables from P:\Library\Folder... to I:\Folder...

I think I can change the field type to long text, find and replace, change type back to hyperlink.

Comment: I don't think you need to change data types. Hyperlink fields have a value that returns a string wrapped in ```#```. Just modify the string and then stick it back in, make sure you keep the ```#``` or it won't work as a hyperlink.

Comment: Actually quite simple. Can use Find/Replace dialog on Hyperlink type field or an UPDATE action SQL using Replace function.

Comment: June7, Could you expand. since the hyperlink is masked by the display text, when i do a find and replace, access cannot find the underlying hyperlink that i want to change. this is why i think that i need to change the field format suck that it is mask#link##, edit the link, change it back to hyperlink format

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Hyperlink field and forgot to test with DisplayText component. Yes, Find/Replace dialog fails but UPDATE works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table Find/Replace dialog will work on Hyperlink field if there is no DisplayText component in hyperlink string.

In either case, an SQL UPDATE action will work, like:

`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table SET field = Replace([field], 'P:\Library\', 'I:\')"`

It is possible to have hyperlink functionality on form and report in ReportView without Hyperlink type field. Of course this will require alternate method than hyperlink field interface to enter file path into text field - probably with VBA executing File System Object dialog. Hyperlink click will not be possible in table but since users should not interact with tables and queries, just forms and reports, this should not be an issue.